# Get ID after inserting Item into SharePoint 2013 Host Web List

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app, visual-studio-2013

I am currently creating a SharePoint 2013 hosted app on Office 365 and I currently have some JavaScript that inserts item into a host web list.

I wondering if it is possible to get the ID of the item that has just been created in the list using the current JavaScript code:

```
function Sumbit() {
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostweburl);

    var web = appCtxSite.get_web();
    var List = web.get_lists().getByTitle('List Title');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var ListItem = List.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    ListItem.set_item('Title', $('#title').val());
    ListItem.set_item('Description', $('#Description').val());

    ListItem.update();

    ctx.load(ListItem);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, QuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, QueryFailed));
});
}


function QuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
console.log("success");


 }

function QueryFailed(sender, args) {
console.log(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
```

I have tried getting the ID inside of the 'QuerySucceeded' function by using:

> ListItem.get_id();

However this was returning '-1' any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try declaring your `ListItem` variable globally, what I can see from your code is that it is local to `Submit` function. Refer below code change.

```
// Declared globally which can be accessible in other functions as well
var ListItem = null;

function Sumbit() {
    $('#submitBtn').click(function () {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostweburl);

        var web = appCtxSite.get_web();
        var List = web.get_lists().getByTitle('List Title');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem = List.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        ListItem.set_item('Title', $('#title').val());
        ListItem.set_item('Description', $('#Description').val());

        ListItem.update();

        ctx.load(ListItem);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, QuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, QueryFailed));
    });
}


function QuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    console.log("success");
}

function QueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the function "RefreshLoad()" on the ListItem before using ListItem.get_id(); . Don't forget to use an executequery on your context before re-using it.

Comment: Do you have an example of this please?